# Compare time with earnings date time to plot custom calculations

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have my own script which writes a nice label to each earning date with some calculated financial information. Sadly somehow the label is not plotted any more. It seems that
if time == epsUnixTimestamp does not match any more, but why?

Here is my script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("EPS (by Tradingbee)", overlay=false)

esdSymbolTemplate = "ESD_FACTSET:" + syminfo.prefix + ";" + syminfo.ticker

umsatzwachstum = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "REVENUE_ONE_YEAR_GROWTH", "FQ")
earnings_estimated = request.security(esdSymbolTemplate + ";EARNINGS", "D", open)
earnings_confirmed = request.security(esdSymbolTemplate + ";EARNINGS", "D", close)
eps_forecast = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "EARNINGS_PER_SHARE_BASIC", "FQ")

// Define the offset for previous years
offset = 252 // Assuming 252 trading days in a year

// Fetch earnings data for the previous years
earnings_confirmed_letztes_jahr = request.security(esdSymbolTemplate + ";EARNINGS", "D", close[offset])
earnings_confirmed_vorletztes_jahr = request.security(esdSymbolTemplate + ";EARNINGS", "D", close[2 * offset])

earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_letztem_jahr = 100 * (earnings_confirmed - earnings_confirmed_letztes_jahr) / earnings_confirmed_letztes_jahr
earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_vorletztem_jahr = 100 * (earnings_confirmed - earnings_confirmed_vorletztes_jahr) / earnings_confirmed_vorletztes_jahr

EPS_annual = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "EARNINGS_PER_SHARE_BASIC", "TTM")
PriceEarningsRatio = close / EPS_annual
pe_target = 4 * PriceEarningsRatio * 20

surprise = earnings_confirmed - earnings_estimated
surprise_prozent = 100 * surprise / earnings_estimated

p1 = plot(earnings_confirmed, color=(earnings_confirmed > 0) ? color.green : color.red, title="EPS", linewidth=2)
h0 = plot(0, color=color.black, title="0", linewidth=2)
hmax = plot(math.abs(earnings_confirmed * 6), color=#b2b5be, linewidth=1)

epsUnixTimestamp = request.security(esdSymbolTemplate + ";EARNINGS", "D", time)
//epsUnixBarindex = request.security(esdSymbolTemplate + ";EARNINGS", "D", bar_index)
//label.new(bar_index, 0, str.tostring(epsUnixBarindex) + "\n" + str.tostring(bar_index), color=color.red)


labelcolor = color.gray
if (earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_letztem_jahr > 20 or earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_vorletztem_jahr > 20)
    labelcolor := color.green
if (earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_letztem_jahr > 30 and earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_letztem_jahr > 1.3 * earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_vorletztem_jahr and umsatzwachstum > 10)
    labelcolor := color.new(color.lime, 80)
if (earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_letztem_jahr > 30 and earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_vorletztem_jahr > 50 and umsatzwachstum > 10)
    labelcolor := color.new(color.lime, 80)
if (earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_letztem_jahr < 0 or eps_forecast < 0)
    labelcolor := color.red
if (earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_letztem_jahr < 0 and earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_vorletztem_jahr < 0)
    labelcolor := color.new(color.red, 80)

if time == epsUnixTimestamp
    label.new(bar_index, earnings_confirmed + 0.05, text="EPS: " + str.tostring(earnings_confirmed, "#.##") + "\n %-Vorjahresquartal: " + str.tostring(earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_letztem_jahr, "#.##") + "%" + "\n %-Vor-Vorjahresquartal: " + str.tostring(earnings_prozent_steigerung_zu_vorletztem_jahr, "#.##") + "%" + "\n EPS-Forecast: " + str.tostring(eps_forecast, "#.##") + "\n Umsatzwachstum: " + str.tostring(umsatzwachstum, "#.##") + "%" + "\n PE: " + str.tostring(PriceEarningsRatio, "#.##") + "\n PE-Target: " + str.tostring(pe_target, "#.##"), color=labelcolor)
```